# iOS標準カレンダーの予定からタイトルのみを取得したい

Tags: swift, ios, swift4

下記ページの内容を参考にしながらiOS標準カレンダーのイベントを取得しているのですが、タイトルのみを取り出したいときに何度やってもうまく行きません。
どのようにすればイベントのタイトルのみを取得できますでしょうか。どうか教えてくだいさい！

[SwiftでiOS標準カレンダーを使う方法 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/katzhide/items/47b06736c5bfe60f25d0)

Comment: あなた自身が実際に試したコードなども提示してもらわないと、「うまくいかない」という情報だけではなかなかアドバイスが付かないと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問者さんが参考にしているサイトの[こちら](https://qiita.com/katzhide/items/47b06736c5bfe60f25d0#%E3%82%A4%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E6%96%B0%E8%A6%8F%E7%99%BB%E9%8C%B2)の部分にあるスクリプトの中に以下のような記述があると思います。

```
// イベントを作成して情報をセット
let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
event.title = title
```

ここの`event.title`に注目して欲しいのですが、こちらでイベントのタイトルを設定しています。
つまり裏を返せば`let title = event.title`とすればイベントのタイトルを取得できるということです。
取得したイベント一覧(EKEventの配列)から`title`プロパティを取得すればOKです。

Apple公式ドキュメントを見ると今回質問者さんが使っている[EventKitのリファレンス](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit)があります。
特に[EKEventStore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore)と[EKEvent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit)を見ると大変参考になると思います。

追記：質問者さんが参考にしているサイトの以下の部分で`events`に入る値はおそらくEKEventインスタンスの配列です。

```
// イベントを検索
let events = eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(predicate);
```

なのでタイトルだけを取り出すにはそれぞれの要素でタイトルを取得する必要があります。

```
let titles = []
for event in events {
    titles += event.title
}
```

これで`titles`にタイトルの文字列が配列として入るはずです。

Comment: とても丁寧にお答えしていただきありがとうございます。print(event.title)でrunするとnilと出てきてしまいます。print(events)でrunすると配列で出てくるのでそれのtitleだけとりだしたいので(events.title)や(events[title])などで試しているのですがうまくいきません。具体的なコードを教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: eventsはEKEventインスタンスの配列です。なのでそのまま直接`events.title`では取り出せません。forEachで回すなどして配列の各要素で`title`を取り出せると思います。

Comment: おかげさまで取得することができましたありがとうございます。

Comment: 私の回答がお役に立てたなら幸いです。もしよろしければこの回答を承認していただけると、解決済みとすることができるのでよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 返信遅くなりました。チェックマークをつけたのですがこれでよろしかったでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。これからも24kさんが質問をして、有効な回答がつきましたら回答の承認をお願いします。